# Difference between 切る、切り刻む、刻む

Tags: word-choice, words

What's the difference between these words?

Comment: 切り刻む is something Jack the Ripper liked to do. We don't hear it very often in daily life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most basic differences might be something like this:

> - 切る - **to cut / cut off**
> - 刻む - **to carve into / to slice**

Here are two examples for each word. The first one is *literal* usage, the second on is *figurative* usage.

> - 文字を石に**刻む** - to **carve** letters **into** a rock
> - 心に**刻まれた** - (it) was **carved into** (my) heart

...

> - 紙を**切る** - to **cut** paper
> - 縁{えん}を**切った** - (he) **cut off** (our) relationship

刻む also has the common meaning of "cut thinly" or "slice" as in:

> - ねぎを**刻む** - to **slice** chives

You can combine the two words like this:

> - ねぎを**切り刻む** - to **slice up** chives **very thinly**